# Curl animation(like open page of book) in android

Tags: android, android-animation, page-curl

I am developing an app which include many images(hd) and these images will shown in next/previous by swapping screen left/right respectively. Changing of images should be like **opening book pages(curl animation http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vOYvaNhSHw)** and also on every page, i have to **play different audio files on touching different parts of screens**. I have googled and found many solutions for it but these are not working and showing memory out of bound exception. These urls are

1. https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwu7P5PCpsw
3. [Page curl effect in an Activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973087/page-curl-effect-in-an-activity-in-android)
4. [android taking screenshot of offscreen page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604125/android-taking-screenshot-of-offscreen-page)
5. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP_AlvJqSLQ
6. [Android activity page curl animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727907/android-activity-page-curl-animation)
7. [make animation like page changing when swiped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698207/make-animation-like-page-changing-when-swiped)
8. https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl
9. [Implement page curl on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android)
   .... and many more.

In all above links either memory issue or curl animation is worst, So i can't get help from them.

Please help me to stuck out from these issue. It would be appreciated.

Comment: have u know pager in android

Comment: Thanks Naveen, I have already tried out pager(http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) that works fine but its animation must be like opening pages of book on swapping left or right on screen where as we can use only zoom-in-out, scale animation.

Comment: Harism's curl animation works pretty well except, sometimes it has white flickering if you swipe very fast

Answer (score 3):

can you add below option in manifest. In my case this help me when I have large `bitmap` and `OutOfMemoryError`

```
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: Thanks Satish,  I have already tried this. It was working but animation and smoothness of app (on swapping left/right) become worst.

Comment: i think this happen because you use very large bitmap.they resone to app freez to handel. you can use lazy image load and try again.if have any problem give me  your image load code.

Comment: This definitely helps