# How to make something like this in android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, animation

These pictures [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc7Of.jpg) [/ image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHoUs.jpg) are from Play Book application.
I want to do something similar in my app Are there any resources that would be useful

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/easyflipviewpager-the-flip-animations-for-your-viewpager-fd66b34f4703

Comment: not same animation

Comment: Have you checked links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973285/curl-animationlike-open-page-of-book-in-android)?

Comment: @MuhammedEtellisi actually it has the book-style flipping mode **BookPageFlipTransformer** besides the card-style flipping mode **CardFlipPageTransformer**. https://youtu.be/ibuHv06wdhs https://github.com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipViewPager#-book-flip-example